# How to exit the script if the directories already exist?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, exit-code, file-exists

Bellow there is a PHP code to make multiple directories inside the current directory.
I need to terminate the script in case the directories already exist.
But instead, I get multiple "file exists" warning messages.

**Code**

```
<?php

//Creates multiple directories inside the current directory.

$curdir = getcwd();
$slash = "/0";

for ($dir = 1; $dir <= 12; $dir++){

      $concat = $slash . $dir;

      if (!file_exists($concat)) {

        mkdir($curdir . "$concat" , 0777);

      } else {

        exit("Files already exist.");

      }

} 

?>
```

**Output**

```
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/lampp/htdocs/SQL/mkdir.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your if statement. You are checking a different directory than what you were creating:

```
<?php

$curdir = getcwd();
$slash = "/0";

for ($dir = 1; $dir <= 12; $dir++){

      $concat = $slash . $dir;

      if (!file_exists($curdir . $concat)) {

        mkdir($curdir . $concat , 0777);

      } else {

        exit("Files already exist.");

      }

}
```

Comment: I'm a new user. Tried to vote you up but it doesn't let me. I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: It would be a dream 

Comment: I appreciate your helpful solution 